# Angular 8. Ng2table tabledata refers to a type but it is used as a value here

Tags: angular, typescript

I am integrating an `ng2table` component to my angular app and I faced this error. The code looks like this.

```
import { TableData } from '../table-data';
```

the error is

```
cannot find module 'table-data' or its corresponding type declaration.
```

I created a type with this code

```js
export interface TableData {
  Name: string;
  Position: string;
  Office: string;
  "Extn.": number;
  Start: Date;
  Salary: number;
}
```

and placed it in table-data.ts file. Then I got the following error in this line of code.

```js
private data: Array<any> = TableData;
```

The error is

'TableData' only refers to a type but it is being used as a value here.

I made some google search and what I got is that it may be because of the deceleration or an import issue. can you please help?

Answer (score 0):

The errors say you are trying to fill a variable with a class (or interface or whatever), instead of a value.

```
private data: Array<any> = TableData;
```

should be:

```
private data1: TableData = {}; // empty object
private data2: TableData = null; // empty attribute
private data3: TableData[] = []; // empty array
private data4: TableData[] = null; // empty attribute
```